# Conditional passing of arguments to image

Tags: flutter, dart

This code is *not* working:

```dart
// Uint8List imageBinary

final imageWidget = FadeInImagePlaceholder(
    image: imageBinary == null ? AssetImage('blank.png') : MemoryImage(imageBinary),
    // ...
```

Throwing this error:

> `The argument type 'Object' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'ImageProvider<Object>'.`

### However

But this code works:

```dart
// Uint8List imageBinary

final imageWidget = FadeInImagePlaceholder(
    image: MemoryImage(imageBinary),
    // ...
```

Also this code works too:

```dart
// Uint8List imageBinary

final imageWidget = FadeInImagePlaceholder(
    image: AssetImage('blank.png'),
    // ...
```

why?

Comment: The `FadeInImagePlaceholder` code is [here](https://github.com/flutter/gallery/blob/8ec7fdb5d599f8fd085b1d18de6f24a765fd07af/lib/layout/image_placeholder.dart#L14).

Comment: Uint8List imageBinary;
     final   i = FadeInImagePlaceholder(
          placeholder: null,
         image: imageBinary == null ? Image.asset('blank.png') : MemoryImage(imageBinary)
     );

Comment: @HardikMehta `The getter 'image' isn't defined for the type 'AssetImage'.` is received.

Comment: But your code works fine for me. Not giving any error.

Comment: @HardikMehta Well, that's strange. Thanks.